# Save a jsp-session-attribute when clicking link

Tags: html, jsp, session-variables

I'm trying to make a website for an application we designed, and I'm struggling to find a method to save a session-attribute. I have the following code:

```
<%
    for (int i=0;i< (Integer) session.getAttribute("aantalLijsten");i++){
        %>
        <a href="wishList.jsp"><%= session.getAttribute("wishList"+i) %></a>
        <%
    } 
%>
```

where the attributes have been set in a servlet. I want to make a list of links, but they all have to go to the same page. On that page, I will generate the right content, based on the attribute wishList, which is the name on which the user clicked. Can I save that attribute in some way? Something like an "action on click: setAttribute("currentList", getAttribute("wishList"+i))"?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then Try this:

```
<%
    for (int i=0;i< (Integer) session.getAttribute("aantalLijsten");i++){
%>
    <a href="wishList.jsp?param1="session.getAttribute("wishList"+i)><%= session.getAttribute("wishList"+i) %></a>
<%
    } 
%>
```

and in *servlet* you can access it as

```
String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
```

but I strongly recommend you to not use scriplets in your JSP, have a look at [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)